Purge message from expiry queue
In ActiveMQ Artemis, while sending message I'm setting expiry. When message are not processed from expiry queue with 48 hrs, is there a way I can clear them?

Try using the <expiry-delay> address setting on the actual expiry address and unsetting the <expiry-address> which means expired messages will just be dropped. For example, if your expiry address is named ExpiryAddress then you'd have an address setting like this:
<address-setting match="ExpiryAddress">
   <expiry-address/>
   <expiry-delay>172800000</expiry-delay> <!-- 48 hours in milliseconds -->
</address-setting>

See more in the documentation.
